# Fulfilling an array of promises with Q

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, promise, q

I'm trying to count the number of individuals that are assigned to each shift by finding them when I search in my Mongodb database. I then am trying to add that value to the shift's object within my shifts array. Unfortunately, it does not seem that the code is proceeding through the Q.all section. I am not very familiar with the concepts of promises or Q, so I am not sure if I have made a very careless error or not.

```
dbFunctions.algorithm = function(collectionName, callback){
    var collection = dbConnection.collection(collectionName);

//order the shifts in order of number of volunteers
var shifts = [ { value : 'setup' }, { value : '8:30' }, { value : '9:00' }, { value : '9:30' }, { value : '10:00' }, { value : 'cleanup' } ];

var promiseList = [];
for(var i=0; i < shifts.length; i++) {
    promiseList[i] = Q.defer();
}

for ( var j=0; j<shifts.length; j++ ){
    var promise=promiseList[j];

    var shift = shifts[j];

    collection.find({ 'Available[]' : { $elemMatch : { $eq : shift.value } } }).toArray(function(err, result) {
         shift.count = result.length;
         promise.resolve();
    });

}  

console.log(promiseList);
console.log(_.map(promiseList,'promise'));
console.log("here1");
Q.all(_.map(promiseList,'promise')).then(function(value){
    console.log("here2");
    shifts.sort(function (value1, value2){
    return value1.count - value2.count;
    });
    console.log(shifts);

});


}
```

Within the Q.all section of the code, I am trying to sort the shifts array based on these count values. This is the message I am getting from console.log(_.map(promiseList,'promise')); :

```
[ { state: 'pending' },
  { state: 'pending' },
  { state: 'pending' },
  { state: 'pending' },
  { state: 'pending' },
  { state: 'pending' } ]
here1
```

Comment: if you change `Q.all(_.map(promiseList,'promise'))` to `Q.all(promiseList)` does it work any better?

Comment: When I do that it goes through the Q.all section of code; however, it only prints out this:                                                                                                                                                                 here2
[ { value: 'setup' },
  { value: '8:30' },
  { value: '9:00' },
  { value: '9:30' },
  { value: '10:00' },
  { value: 'cleanup' } ]

Comment: So the counts are not being stored and the array is not being sorted

Comment: I see the problem now ...  are you sure that there's absolutely no shift with a .count? I'm sure the last one will have it

Comment: check the code - in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jaromanda/c35s1jaf/) - does that do what you want?

Comment: One problem is that `var shift` in the for loop will be the last shift by the time anyof those asynchronous functions execute

Comment: Yes the console.log(shifts) statement is printing all the shifts within the array in the original order without a .count. I tried even directly checking the array's last index just in case and that one didn't have a count either

Comment: hmmm ... the flow of execution is not even what I thought it was then :p - must mean the Q.all().then is executing before all of the promises are resolved - it's your use of `_.map(promiseList,'promise')` that confuses me - what the heck is that second argument for - all uses of _.map I've seen (underscore and lodash) the second argument is a function, not a string

Comment: I tried the other code too and that gave me the same result of the array having no counts

Comment: can you try [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/jaromanda/c35s1jaf/1/) it doesn't use Q promises it uses native ones - assuming you have a not too old version of node

Comment: Hey that worked! :D Thank you so much for your help!!!!

Comment: Have a wonderful day!

Comment: Goes to show not all promise libraries work

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Q library used in the question isn't a Promise/A+ one, so it's not clear why the code in `Q.all(...).then` is apparently running "too soon"

changing the code to use native Promise (available in node for a long time now) yields the following tidier code - which actually works!

```
dbFunctions.algorithm = function(collectionName, callback){
    var collection = dbConnection.collection(collectionName);

    var shifts = [ { value : 'setup' }, { value : '8:30' }, { value : '9:00' }, { value : '9:30' }, { value : '10:00' }, { value : 'cleanup' } ];

    Promise.all(shifts.map(function(shift) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            collection.find({ 'Available[]' : { $elemMatch : { $eq : shift.value } } }).toArray(function(err, result) {
                shift.count = result.length;
                resolve();
            });
        });
    })).then(function(results) { // not actually used as the shifts array is updated directly
        shifts.sort(function (value1, value2){
            return value1.count - value2.count;
        });
        console.log(shifts);
    });
}
```